# update multiple records using mongoosejs in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble updating multiple records using mongoosejs and node. For some reason, I only update a single record, even if multiple match. I've also noticed that the callback will not fire after .update(). I'm not getting any error messages. What's going on here?

```
Page.find({status:'queued'})
    .limit(queue_limit-queue.length)
    .update({ status: 'active' },{ multi: true },function(err,num){
        console.log("updated "+num);
        //this callback will never fire, but a single record will be updated and marked as active.                                                                                                 
    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`Query#update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) doesn't accept an `options` parameter, but [`Model.update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) does.  So you'd want to rewrite this as:

```
Page.update({status:'queued'}, {status: 'active'}, {multi: true}, 
    function(err, num) {
        console.log("updated "+num);
    }
);
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the `limit` call in the chain, but you can't use that in an update.

**UPDATE**

The above query will update all docs where `{status: 'queued'}`.  Your only choices with `update` are just the first matching one `{multi: false}` or all matches `{multi: true}`.

Sounds like you need to rework things to take docs off your queue one at a time and switch to [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) instead of `update` so you have access to the doc you've updated from `'queued'` to `'active'`.

Comment: The point of the limit is to make it so I only update 10 records. Your query looks like it would update everything with `{status:'queued'}`. I also need the first callback I used in my example to see what records I'm changing (and not just the number affected).

Comment: @Sammaye: Thanks, I was worried about that. What are the current best practices for something like this?

Comment: @devnill The edit seems to do a good job of answering that, unfortunately it is not an easy thing to do and there is no easy right way atm