# update multiple records using mongoose in node with dynamic query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i already gone through below answers:-
[update multiple records using mongoosejs in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674170/update-multiple-records-using-mongoosejs-in-node)

[Update multiple docs with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667974/update-multiple-docs-with-different-values)

but in my case my query is dynamic , means i need to query dynamically
based on obj,
I am also not sure if forEach is a goof solution 
Is there any better alternative for same, as this is taking too much time in each time.

```
     req.body.forEach(function (obj) {
    myModel.find(
        {
            country: obj.country,
            product: obj.product,
            month: parseInt(obj.month),

        }
    ).update({
            $set: {
                value: parseInt(obj.value),
                'lastmodified': Date.now()
            }
        },
        { upsert: true},
        function (err) {
            //callback();
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            return res.status(200);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Is `req.body` an array or an object with key value pairs? array.forEach works on arrays. `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object. Maybe if you show more of your code more people might be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is helpful but it looked like you weren't sure about parsing `req.body` to find the documents. This is just pseudo code. Maybe it will give you an idea.

```
app.put("/post", function(req, res){
    myModel.find({
        country : req.body.country,
        product : req.body.product,
        month : parseInt(req.body.month)
    })
    myModel.save(function(err, results){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log(results)
        res.send(results)
    })
})
```

Comment: since I am passing multiple objects in one request, req.body.country will not have that info, that is the reason i am using "  req.body.forEach(function (obj) {"  to parse through each object